# Xamarin Android call WebAPI Connection Fail

Tags: android, xamarin, webapi

I've create an app in Xamarin, the app will call a WebAPI to login and retrieve data from server.

The WebAPI is http, not https.

The calling of web API success in iOS emulator, iOS device, and Android emulator. (I do not have android device to test).

But when deploy to user using Android phone, calling of Web API fail with error message Connection Fail.

No idea why this happen. Please guide me what I can check.

Thanks

Comment: What is the detailed error message ? Is there any error code ?

Comment: The error message should be a message catch from exception, it only show "Connection Fail". I had try to amend the program to see if can return more error information. Pending user reply now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the setting is set correctly in Properties .

HttpClient implementation -> Android

SSL/TLS implementaiton -> Native TLS 1.2+

[image]

#### Update

Add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` into AndroidManifest .

Create a new xml named network_security_config.xml , add it into res/xml folder .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
     <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: The WebAPI server do not set with SSL cert, the url is start with http.

Comment: https request is required after Android 9.0 , if you still want to request with http , you have to declare something in manifest ,   check my update below .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your android emulator is set up correctly and is connected to the internet

Comment: No, Android Emulator can call the WebAPI successfully, it's fail when run on actual Android device.